# Error while rendering Map from CARTO without any code change

Tags: carto, google-maps, error, carto-js

I have suddenly started getting error while rendering US map.  This has come without any code changes.  We are using CARTO.js.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
    at d.initialize (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:21:21536)
    at d.a.View (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:6:28431)
    at d.constructor (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:16:22865)
    at d [as constructor] (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:6:30704)
    at new d (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:6:30704)
    at Object.eval [as current] (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:23:13955)
    at window.vizjson (eval at module.exports (addScript.js?3fe7:27), <anonymous>:16:25517)
    at viz.json?callback=vizjson:1
```

Comment: Could you share any link or details on how you are getting this error? Also, if you have already found the answer, please share it instead of keeping this open.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the issue was related to Google Maps (3.31 to 3.34) changes in their API versions.  Carto uses Google Maps underneath and any changes are opaque to the end developers.

There is no fix currently in place.